# Pine Script: How to display a line starting at a specified Hour:Minute if it falls timewise in the middle of the candles?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to draw line e.g. @09:48 New York time, but i want it to draw it even if the resolution is 5m or 15m etc. In order to do so, i have to get the Minute part from the session "8" and round it to the next 0 e.g. 09:50 if resolution is 5m and to e.g. 09:45 if the resolution is 15m. I think this should be the standard functionality of tradingview but maybe in the next version it will be implemented. If there is a generalistic solution to this, then i think that it would deserve to be a library.

below a sample code, which does not display the horizontal line drawn @09:48 at e.g. 5m resolution. But it displays the same line, if i change the resolution to 3m (or 2m or 1m), because the there are 3m candles which start at 09:48 and no candle @5m resolution does start @09:48; they start e.g. 0940,0945,0950,0955 etc.

```
//@version=5
indicator("custom lines", "custom lines ", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count=500, max_boxes_count=500, max_bars_back=500)

timezone = "America/New_York"
line6_label = input.string("09:48","label", group="6 . line")
line6_Toggle = input.bool(true,"Enabled","", inline="6 ", group="6 . line")
line6_session = input.session('0948-0949:1234567', "09:48", group="6 . line")
line6_color = input.color(#00eeff, "", inline="6 ", group="6 . line")
line6_linestyle_input = input.string("Solid", "", options=["Solid", "Dotted", "Dashed"], inline="6 ", group="6 . line")
line6_ExtendInput = input.bool(true, "Extend right", group="6 . line")
label_size_input = input.string("Small", "Size", options=["Small", "Normal", "Huge"], group="Labels")
labelOffset = (input.int(5,"Label Offset", group="Labels") * timeframe.multiplier*600000)
labelsize = label_size_input == "Small" ? size.small : label_size_input == "Normal" ? size.normal : size.huge


line6_time_unshifted = time("1", line6_session,timezone)
minuteDifference6 = (line6_time_unshifted - line6_time_unshifted[1]) / 60000
line6_time = ( timeframe.multiplier>minuteDifference6 and timeframe.isminutes ) ? line6_time_unshifted + (timeframe.multiplier-minuteDifference6)*60000 : line6_time_unshifted

// Debug does not display anythiong other than 0 for line6_time_unshifted or line6_time
//if (time >= chart.left_visible_bar_time and time <= chart.right_visible_bar_time)
//    label.new(bar_index, high, text=str.tostring(minute(line6_time_unshifted)))
linestyle_6 = line6_linestyle_input == "Solid" ? line.style_solid : line6_linestyle_input == "Dotted" ? line.style_dotted : line.style_dashed
//line6 
var line6_open  = 0.0
if line6_time
    if not line6_time[1]
        line6_open  := open
    else
        line6_open := math.max(open, line6_open)

//line6 
var label lab6 = na
var line lin6 = na
if line6_Toggle
    if line6_open != line6_open[1]
        if barstate.isconfirmed
            line.set_x2(lin6 , line6_time)
            lin6 := line.new(line6_time, line6_open, last_bar_time, line6_open, xloc.bar_time, line6_ExtendInput ? extend.right : extend.none, line6_color, linestyle_6, 1)
            lab6  := label.new(last_bar_time + labelOffset , line6_open, line6_label, xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, na, label.style_none, line6_color, labelsize, text.align_right)
            label.delete(lab6 [1])
            line.delete(lin6 [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution for this using sessions, but just a workaround, which can be usefull to others with similar problems: I changed the implementation using integer inputs for hours and minutes pairs like

```
    start_session_hour = input.int(...) 
    end_session_hour = input.int(...) 
    start_session_minute = input.int(...) 
    end_session_minute = input.int(...)
```

etc. Then the trick is using timeframe.multiplier (and checking that we are in a intraday timeframe like timeframe.isintraday) and rounding the time so that in coincides with the start of the nearest candle of the selected timeframe. This works for small differences like 0948 and 5m timeframe, but not very good for 0948 and 1h timeframe, because here the difference is 12 minutes and the line is drawn farther away from the intended price level.